# Adding METRONIC to a Django project

Tags: javascript, django, templates, block

im adding METRONIC Ui from (http://themeforest.net/item/metronic-responsive-admin-dashboard-template/4021469) and when i start to adding or splitting the theme into blocks as there are tons of .js scripts i loose some functionalities. Does anyone did this before??

Cheers!

Comment: I've done this with a few purchased themes (split the theme into a base template and individual page templates). It's always messy, they're generally not coded well. The best thing to do is compare the DOM of your Django-generated page with the DOM of a working page from the template, and fix the differences. It's a pain.

Answer (score 0):

I looked extensively on this and found out that there is very less support for this theme on Django platform. But I used the guidelines mentioned withing this article to help me do the same [Metronic Admin Dashboard with Django](https://medium.com/feldstudie/metronic-admin-dashboard-with-django-d803fc07974d). Hope this is helpful to start the development.